# Strange androidNDK - java, only the first line of code is running

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio, ant, android-ndk

i have a method something like this in my code (java).

```
public void DoSomeStuff() {
Log.i(TAG,"1");
Log.i(TAG,"2");
Log.i(TAG,"3");
}
```

This is called from C++ through JNI. I'm 100% sure the JNI works and has nothing to do with my problem.
The problem is: Only the first line of the code runs (the output is "1"), and the rest gets ignored. It doesn't matter what i write in the first line... only that gets executed.
There aren't any error messages, freezes, or any relevant information to help in debugging.
I have also tried to clear the bin/gen folders but no success.
The worst part is that, sometimes it works... and sometimes it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Probably a cache problem. Delete the apk from your computer and uninstall the app from your device.

Comment: One way to tell would be to change the "1" to "4".  If you run it again and see "4", you know the program is being updated and mysteriously refusing to run more than one line.  If you still see "1", then you're still running the old APK.

Answer (score 0):

you could post the code for `i` method, maybe there is something within its body that is causing this behaviour?
Have you tried calling different methods? Not neccessarly from Log?
Good luck.